How to add ! after name string?
In the print tab at the bottom I am trying to add an exclamation point after the 'name' string, how do I do this without adding a space?
# get name as a string
name = input('What is your name? \n')
# get age as an int
age = int(input('How old are you? \n'))
# calculate birth year
birth_year = (2024 - age)
# print greeting
print('Hello', name, 'You were born in', birth_year)

I tried putting it after the comma but it adds a space, any help would be appreciated.

Using this particular method, you could use print('Hello ', name, '. You were born in ', birth_year, '!', sep=''). But using an f-string is perhaps easier: print(f'Hello {name}. You were born in {birth_year}!'). Incidentally, your birth_year will only be correct for people who are born before or on the current day of the year.

You could do: print('Hello', name+'!',  ..., but maybe using an f-string is easier.

print(f'Hello, {name} !, You were born in, {birth_year}')
